# How can I get the externalname of a column using IronPython in Spotfire?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Currently I need to change the name of a column depending on specific criteria but to do that I'd like to refer to that column by its ExternalName rather than its name.

```
aColumn = Document.ActiveDataTableReference.Columns["I_id"].Name
```

unfortunately this doesn't work.

```
aColumn = Document.ActiveDataTableReference.Columns["I_id"].ExternalName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're very close! `ExternalName` isn't a property of the [`DataColumn` object](http://stn.spotfire.com/dxp/html/AllMembers_T_Spotfire_Dxp_Data_DataColumn.htm), which is, I suppose you've figured out, why your approach isn't working.

in fact, `ExternalName` is an item represented by the [`DataColumnProperties.DefaultProperties` class](http://stn.spotfire.com/dxp/html/AllMembers_T_Spotfire_Dxp_Data_DataColumnProperties_DefaultProperties.htm). you would actually access this as if it were a custom-defined **Column Property** like so:

```
col_ext_name = Document.ActiveDataTableReference.Columns["I_id"].Properties["ExternalName"]

print(col_ext_name)

>> index_id
```

Comment: thanks!  is there an easy way to reference the externalname without knowing the column name?  in our setup, the column name is dynamic and can change however the external name will be stable?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to directly reference a column by `ExternalName`, but you could use something like `for col in Document.ActiveDataTableReference.Columns: if col.Properties["ExternalName"] = "some_name": do_stuff()`

Comment: that's how I was doing it.  just thinking I might have missed something.  thanks!